# Is it possible to set default folder to be published using 'npm publish'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, npm-publish, ng-packagr

I'm currently developing an Angular library package using **ng-packagr**. Apparently the built result is generated under './dist' folder and it contains all the files (including package.json, js, and d.ts files) that I want to publish to the npm server and that needs to be the root of my package.

Long story short, I want to be able to publish ./dist folder from the root folder with 'npm publish' command. **Is it possible to set the default folder to publish (other than publishing the root folder)?** I know we can use `npm publish dist`, but the thing is my teammates could accidentally do `npm publish` on the root folder and it makes the whole root folder get published.

Comment: You can change what `npm publish` does by editing package.json, assuming typical npm project structure.

Comment: then you can write scripts in your `package.json` for everyone to use like `publish:npm publish dist` .

Comment: @Sachin , tried it, but then it recursively published and eventually stopped due to same version error

Comment: I don't know the error but  `publish: cd ./dist && npm publish` might help you.

Comment: Above suggestions won't work for me: Couldn't find a package.json file (in the dist folder); even if I copy it there, it cascades with The specified path does not exist: 'tsconfig.build.json'.